# Photos does not have the necessary permissions to create a library in the folder that you selected

Tags: macos, photos, external-disk, photos.app

I'm attempting to create a new macOS Photos.app library on a secondary hard drive.

In the `Choose Library` window, when I select `Create New...` and select the external HDD, I get the error:

> **The library could not be created.**
>
> Photos does not have the necessary permissions to create a library in the folder that you selected.

[image: The library could not be created.]

Why can't I use the external hard drive for my Mac Photos Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My external HDD was in the HFS+ file format. The system's boot SSD was using the newer APFS.

I used Disk Utility to reformat the disk as APFS.

After switching to APFS I re-created the new Photos library and it worked fine.

> We can move our Photos Libraries to an external drive, but the drive needs to be correctly formatted as MacOS Extended (Journaled) or APFS and locally mounted.

Pre-APFS file systems *should* work, but for some reason it wasn't working. Perhaps related to permissions, or the the file system itself. Switching to APFS fixed it for me.

---

I found a great resource for this question here:

> Where is it safe to store a Photos Library? Requirements for the location of a Photos Library - 2019 version
>
> https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250000663